# Jquery wait until all animation finish before starting new one

Tags: jquery, animation

I have menu with slideDown/slideup animations attached to hover event.

If i hover over next menu position, while previous is still animated with slideDown, i want to wait for slideDown to finish and only then launch slideUp for current position.

I tried to use promise object, but it does not work at all.

```
$('.menu-2>ul>li').each(function(){
    $(this).hover(
        function(){
            var choice = $('ul', this);
            ('.menu-2>ul>li>ul').promise().done(function(  ) {
                choice.slideDown();

            });

        },
        function(){
            $('ul', this).slideUp(200);
        } 
    );
});
```

Comment: My initial thought is that it probably has to do with document ready not being used. Check this out https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Not really, i just pasted portion of code. It works all right without promise object, animations are binded to hover event.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a callback after slideDown finish. Try example:

```
choice.slideDown("fast",function(){your function})
```

this is call only is animation finish

**UPDATE**

```
$('.menu-2>ul>li').each(function(){
    $(this).hover(
        function(){
            var choice = $('ul', this);
            ('.menu-2>ul>li>ul').promise().done(function(  ) {
                choice.slideDown(500);

            });

        },
        function(){
            $('ul', this).delay(500).slideUp(200);
        } 
    );
});
```

Comment: How can i connect this callback to hover (mouseout portion of it) event?

Comment: i have add a delay between both slide. please try